# Redimensionar un JPanel dentro de un BoxLayout

Tags: java

Estoy tratando de acomodar unos paneles, el panel principal tiene un *BorderLayout* y sobre este, le agrego un panel que se llama `jpIzquierda(BorderLayot.WEST)`, al panel *jpIzquierda* se asigno un *BoxLayout*. y le agrego un panel con *JComboBox(jpCarreras)*, un JList (jpLista) y un Boton.

[image: adjunto la imagen]

Quiero acomodar estos elementos de manera tal, que panel *jpCarreras*, quede mas chico y el botón centrado.

Les dejo el código:

```
jpIzqueirda = new JPanel();
jpIzqueirda.setLayout(new BoxLayout(jpIzqueirda, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

jpCarrera = new JPanel();  
        
jpCarrera.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Carreras: "));
jcCarreras = new JComboBox<Carrera>();
ControladorPanelCarrera.actualizarCombo(jcCarreras); //CARGO EL COMBOBOX
jpCarrera.add(jcCarreras); 
jpIzqueirda.add(jpCarrera);
        
jpMaterias = new JPanel();
jpMaterias.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Materias de la Carrera: "));
jlMaterias = new JList<Materia>();
Carrera c = (Carrera) Facultad.buscarCarrera(jcCarreras.getSelectedItem().toString());
jlMaterias.setModel(modelList(c));
        
jpMaterias.add(jlMaterias);
jpIzqueirda.add(jpMaterias);

botonEditar = new JButton("Editar Materia");
jpIzqueirda.add(botonEditar);
```

Comment: Intenta con `jpCarrera.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300,100));` por ejemplo.

Answer (score 0):

Para acomodar los elementos en el panel jpIzquierda de la manera que deseas, puedes utilizar los métodos setPreferredSize() y setAlignmentX() de la clase JPanel.

Por ejemplo, si quieres que el panel jpCarrera tenga un tamaño preferido más pequeño, puedes agregar el siguiente código después de crear el panel:

```
jpCarrera.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(150, 100));
```

Esto establecerá el tamaño preferido del panel en 150 píxeles de ancho por 100 píxeles de alto. Puedes ajustar estos valores según tus necesidades.

Para centrar el botón en el panel jpIzquierda, puedes agregar el siguiente código después de agregar el botón al panel:

```
botonEditar.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
```

Esto hará que el botón se centre en el eje X del panel, dejando el espacio igual a ambos lados del botón.

El código completo podría verse así:

```
jpIzqueirda = new JPanel();
jpIzqueirda.setLayout(new BoxLayout(jpIzqueirda, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

jpCarrera = new JPanel();  

jpCarrera.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Carreras: "));
jcCarreras = new JComboBox<Carrera>();
ControladorPanelCarrera.actualizarCombo(jcCarreras); //CARGO
```